# selectInput only outputs first option

Tags: r, shiny, reactive, selectinput

I am writing a shiny app to manipulate daily percentage distributions of call arrivals per interval via drag and drop. 
I am trying to display one day only via selectInput. 
However, the DataTable Output and Plot Output do not change when I select another day than Monday (first option in selectInput), i.e., the outputs (datatable and plotly) only display Monday regardless of what I am selecting via selectInput.

Appreciate your help! Thank you in advance!

Dummy data:

```
save_name2 <- paste("Percentage_Forecasts.csv")
df_MON<-data.frame(b=c("MON 07:00","MON 07:30","MON 08:00","MON 08:30","MON 09:00","MON 09:30","MON 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
df_TUE<-data.frame(b=c("TUE 07:00","TUE 07:30","TUE 08:00","TUE 08:30","TUE 09:00","TUE 09:30","TUE 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
df_WED<-data.frame(b=c("WED 07:00","WED 07:30","WED 08:00","WED 08:30","WED 09:00","WED 09:30","WED 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
df_THU<-data.frame(b=c("THU 07:00","THU 07:30","THU 08:00","THU 08:30","THU 09:00","THU 09:30","THU 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
df_FRI<-data.frame(b=c("FRI 07:00","FRI 07:30","FRI 08:00","FRI 08:30","FRI 09:00","FRI 09:30","FRI 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
df_SAT<-data.frame(b=c("SAT 07:00","SAT 07:30","SAT 08:00","SAT 08:30","SAT 09:00","SAT 09:30","SAT 10:00"),a=c(15,20,14,6,10,15,20))
```

Here is my ui.R:

```
ui <- fluidPage( titlePanel("Prozentuale Verteilung Prognosewoche"),
                 fluidRow(

                   column(selectInput(inputId = "dataset",
                                      label = "Choose a weekday",
                                      choices = c("MON", "TUE","WED","THU","FRI","SAT")),

                          DTOutput("table"),width = 5,downloadButton("downloadData", "Save")),
                   column(12, plotlyOutput("p"))))
```

Here is my server.R:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

#i think here is where the problem starts!
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$dataset,
           "MON" = df_MON,
           "TUE" = df_TUE,
           "WED" = df_WED,
           "THU" = df_THU,
           "FRI" = df_FRI,
           "SAT" = df_SAT)
  })


  rv <- reactiveValues(
    x = isolate(datasetInput())$b,
    y = isolate(datasetInput())$a)

  grid <- reactive({
    data.frame(y = rv$y, length=180)})

  output$p <- renderPlotly({
    circles <- map2(rv$x,
                    rv$y, 
                    ~list(
                      type = "circle",
                      xanchor = .x,
                      yanchor = .y,
                      x0 = -4, x1 = 4,
                      y0 = -4, y1 = 4,
                      xsizemode = "pixel", 
                      ysizemode = "pixel",
                      # other visual properties
                      fillcolor = "orange",
                      line = list(color = "transparent") ) )


    plot_ly(grid(), type="scatter", mode='lines+markers',  width = 1200, height = 300) %>%
      add_trace(y = grid()$y, x = isolate(datasetInput())$b,mode='lines+markers') %>%
      layout(shapes = circles) %>%
      config(edits = list(shapePosition = TRUE))
  })

  output$table <-renderDT(rbind({data.frame(rv$x,rv$y)}, c(NULL,sum(rv$y))),colnames=c("Weekday/Time", "Percentage"),width = 800,options = list(
    lengthMenu = list(c(15,31), list('15','31')),
    pageLength = 15,  initComplete = JS(
      "function(settings, json) {",
      "$(this.api().table().body()).css({'font-size': '70%'});",
      "}")
  ))

  observe({
    ed <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
    shape_anchors <- ed[grepl("^shapes.*anchor$", names(ed))]
    if (length(shape_anchors) != 2) return()
    row_index <- unique(readr::parse_number(names(shape_anchors)) + 1)
    pts <- as.numeric(shape_anchors)
    rv$y[row_index] <- pts[2]
  })

  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){save_name2}, 
    content = function(fname){
      write.table(data.frame(rv$x,rv$y), row.names=FALSE, sep=";", fname,col.names=c("Weekday/Calendar Week","Percentage"))
    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: There seems to be some important code missing above as when I run the app it breaks with `object 'df_MON' not found`

Comment: df_MON is a data frame containing the values per interval for monday

Comment: We need some dummy data to properly test

Comment: Added dummy data :)

Comment: Much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited these parts and removed the `isolate`'s:

```
    rv <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
        rv$x = datasetInput()$b
        rv$y = datasetInput()$a
    })
```

and

```
add_trace(y = grid()$y, x = rv$x,mode='lines+markers')
```

Full server code:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

    #i think here is where the problem starts!
    datasetInput <- reactive({
        switch(input$dataset,
               "MON" = df_MON,
               "TUE" = df_TUE,
               "WED" = df_WED,
               "THU" = df_THU,
               "FRI" = df_FRI,
               "SAT" = df_SAT)
    })


    rv <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
        rv$x = datasetInput()$b
        rv$y = datasetInput()$a
    })

    grid <- reactive({
        data.frame(y = rv$y, length=180)})

    output$p <- renderPlotly({
        circles <- map2(rv$x,
                        rv$y, 
                        ~list(
                            type = "circle",
                            xanchor = .x,
                            yanchor = .y,
                            x0 = -4, x1 = 4,
                            y0 = -4, y1 = 4,
                            xsizemode = "pixel", 
                            ysizemode = "pixel",
                            # other visual properties
                            fillcolor = "orange",
                            line = list(color = "transparent") ) )


        plot_ly(grid(), type="scatter", mode='lines+markers',  width = 1200, height = 300) %>%
            add_trace(y = grid()$y, x = rv$x,mode='lines+markers') %>%
            layout(shapes = circles) %>%
            config(edits = list(shapePosition = TRUE))
    })

    output$table <-renderDT(rbind({data.frame(rv$x,rv$y)}, c(NULL,sum(rv$y))),colnames=c("Weekday/Time", "Percentage"),width = 800,options = list(
        lengthMenu = list(c(15,31), list('15','31')),
        pageLength = 15,  initComplete = JS(
            "function(settings, json) {",
            "$(this.api().table().body()).css({'font-size': '70%'});",
            "}")
    ))

    observe({
        ed <- event_data("plotly_relayout")
        shape_anchors <- ed[grepl("^shapes.*anchor$", names(ed))]
        if (length(shape_anchors) != 2) return()
        row_index <- unique(readr::parse_number(names(shape_anchors)) + 1)
        pts <- as.numeric(shape_anchors)
        rv$y[row_index] <- pts[2]
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
        filename = function(){save_name2}, 
        content = function(fname){
            write.table(data.frame(rv$x,rv$y), row.names=FALSE, sep=";", fname,col.names=c("Weekday/Calendar Week","Percentage"))
        })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Glad to help! Making it reproducible was the key :)